# How to create a Unit test that should exclude extraneous dto properties?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

```html
class SampleDTO {
    public readonly code: string
    public readonly name: string
    public readonly type: string
}

const sampleBodyRequest = {
    code: 'NZD',
    name: 'New Zealand dollar',
    type: 'fiat',
    color: 'white'
}

describe('validate', () => {

    it('should exclude extraneous dto properties', () => {
        
    })
})
```

Is there a simple way to create this assertion?

Need to be mocha and sinon only. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
const assert = require('assert');
...
describe('validate', () => {

    it('should exclude extraneous dto properties', () => {
       const expected = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new SampleDTO());
       const actual = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(theFunctionUnderTestThatConvertsTheInputToDTO(sampleBodyRequest));
       assert.deepStrictEqual(actual, expected);        
    })
})
```